# Deis docker image deploy

Tags: docker, deis

Trying to deploy the go-example app from the documentation : 
http://docs.deis.io/en/latest/using_deis/using-docker-images/#using-docker-images

I am skipping the "Prepare the application" bit and trying to deploy the example docker app gabrtv/example-go

I run the following to do the deployment :

```
deis pull gabrtv/example-go:latest
```

Does not work I get the following :

```
"GET Image Error (404: {\"error\": \"Tag not found\"})"
```

Looking at 
https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/gabrtv/example-go/tags/manage/

The latest tag is there.
Pulling it with

```
docker pull gabrtv/example-go
```

it get's pulled correctly. So I am not really sure what I am doing wrong.

Using the controller API with curl gives me the same result :

```
     curl -i -X POST \
     -H "Authorization: token $TOKEN" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -d '{"image":"gabrtv/example-go"}' \
     http://$IP:$PORT/v1/apps/dummyapp2/builds/
```

Anyone have any idea?

Comment: Seems to work on version 1.1.1 https://github.com/deis/deis/issues/2916

Answer (score 0):

Are you also skipping the section 'Create an Application'?  In Deis an application is a group of container being load balanced to by the routing layer.  In the example they have you create a folder named 'example-go', cd into it, and then run 'deis create'.  This defaults to the current folders name for the application name.  Instead you can run:

```
deis create example-go
```

Then you can run the deis pull command with the '-a' flag telling it which application to to associate the container with.

```
deis pull gabrtv/example-go:latest -a example-go
```

Comment: Hi, no it turns out it's a bug in Deis or more specifically the registry timeout values. https://github.com/deis/deis/issues/2916